# Group and order , select details from ravendb in c#

Tags: c#, ravendb

```
public class Award
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Awardor { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Awardee { get; set; }
}
```

**input saved in the ravendb :**

```
1 DOT 1000 YSI
2 DOJ 5000 PSI
3 DOA 6000 YSI
4 DOT 2000 PPP
5 DOT 1000 YSI
6 DOA 4000 PSI
```

**I want output be like this**

**top awardor**

```
DOA 10000                    
DOJ 5000                     
DOT 4000
```

**top awardee**

```
PSI 9000  
YSI 8000  
PPP 2000
```

How to create an index and query it in raven db to fetch top 10 awards by awardor and awardee by grouping amount using C#

Comment: I would suggest looking at the documentation for ravendb: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp

Comment: Looking actively for the help

Comment: Please don't edit to change/extend your question, once you've already received answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (consider to change the name of properties):

```
public class AwardIndex : Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<AwardIndex.Result>
{
      public class Result
      {
           public string AwardeeAwardor { get; set; } //is Awardee or Awardor
           public string ItemType { get; set; } //DOT, DOJ, PSI, ecc
           public double Value { get; set; }
      }

      public AwardIndex()
      {
            AddMap<Award>(items => from item in items
                                   select new Result
                                   {
                                        AwardeeAwardor = "Awardee",
                                        ItemType = item.Awardee,
                                        Value = item.Amount
                                   });

            AddMap<Award>(items => from item in items
                                   select new Result
                                   {
                                        AwardeeAwardor = "Awardor",
                                        ItemType = item.Awardor,
                                        Value = item.Amount
                                   });

            Reduce = items => from item in items
                              group item by new { AwardeeAwardor = item.AwardeeAwardor, ItemType = item.ItemType }
                              into g
                              select new Result
                              {
                                   AwardeeAwardor = g.Key.AwardeeAwardor,
                                   ItemType = g.Key.ItemType,
                                   Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
                              };
       }
}
```

Query:

```
IList<AwardIndex.Result> results = session
                .Query<AwardIndex.Result, AwardIndex>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList(); // do what you need

var awardor = results.Where(x => x.AwardeeAwardor == "Awardor").OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();
var awardee = results.Where(x => x.AwardeeAwardor == "Awardee").OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

awardor.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.AwardeeAwardor + "\t" + x.ItemType + "\t" + x.Value));
Console.WriteLine("_____");
awardee.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.AwardeeAwardor + "\t" + x.ItemType + "\t" + x.Value));
```

Comment: ,Perfect. I tried your index and worked like charm. Now I need to modify the document little bit. I need to add year column to the award document  and sum the value for awardor and awardee  and need to select top awardor and awardee by value for each year

Comment: @BaskerGanesan if it worked accept the answer, anyway i don't think that you can extend your question after 15 days with different details..

Comment: @BaskerGanesan anyway, add Year in the mapping and then add Year in the group by in the reduce